# Declaring Public Variable inside Constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I'm pretty new to Java so this might be a very silly question.

I initialized my variables inside the constructor at first, and then learnt that the scope of those variables will be limited only to the scope

So I tried adding the PUBLIC keyword to the variables, and still doesn't work.
Can someone explain why?

```
class Demo{
  Demo(){
    public int a=3;
    public int b=5;
  }

  int sum(int x, int y){
    return x+y;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Demo obj= new Demo();
    System.out.println(obj.a);
  }
}
```

Comment: Explanation: that's simply not valid Java. If you declare a variable in the constructor, then it is visible *only* within the constructor and nowhere else. You cannot declare a local variable such as this as public, private, or protected. Only class fields (variables declared at the class level) can be declared thusly. For detailed explanation, you will want to search and study the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/).

Comment: Because they should be inside the class but outside the constructor (or any other method)

Comment: Here is a [link to the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.4) that covers what is allowed when declaring *local* variables (as you are doing with the variables within the constructor).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels So it just won't help adding public keyword to a local variable? It still remains local?

Comment: *"So it just won't help adding public keyword to a local variable? It still remains local?"* --  Won't help? No, it won't work; it won't be allowed. It's simply not legal Java and such code won't compile (which you really should be testing out yourself first).

Comment: Simply because you can't have `public` inside code blocks. If you want to have instance variables, you need to write `public int a;` in your class body, i.e. outside of the constructor. Then you can assign a value to `a` inside your constructor.